# When does the left adjoint of the base change functor between categories of algebras over operads preserve quasi-isomorphisms?

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories, operads

I have been thinking about the following question: given a morphism of coloured dg-operads $$\phi: P \longrightarrow Q$$
we derive a lax morphism between their respective monads $T= T_P \longrightarrow T_Q =S$ where $T$ is a monad on a category $C$ and $S$ on a category $D$. As a result we have a base change functor between their categories of algebras
$$\phi_*: S-Alg \longrightarrow T-Alg$$
In case $S-Alg$ has enough coequalizers, this functor has a left adjoint $\phi^{!}$ constructed using an induced colax morphism of monads $(f,\alpha)$, that is, a functor
$f:  C\longrightarrow D$ and a natural transformation
$\alpha: fT \Longrightarrow Sf$, as follows: for $(X,\lambda) \in Alg(T)$, we obtain $\phi^{!}X$ as the coequalizer of $(Sf\lambda, \mu_{fX} \circ S\alpha_X)$, i.e.

[image]

Both categories $C$ and $D$ have a notion of quasi-isomorphisms (and model category structures) by considering them point-wise.

The functor $\phi^{!}$ acts on morphisms $r:X \longrightarrow Y$ of $T$-algebras as follows: it is the induced arrow in the diagram below

[image]

My question is the following: if the functors $S,T$ and $f$ preserve quasi-isomorphisms, does the functor $\phi^{!}$ preserve quasi-isomorphisms?

My first idea was to use homological algebra. However, the only result that I know would help requires that the map $\mu_{fX}\circ S\alpha_X - Sf \lambda_X$ is point-wise a monomorphism, i.e. then we could bottom and top row of the diagram to short exact sequences. However, this will not be the case.

My second idea would be to look at model category techniques. The objects $SfX$ and $SfTX$ are cofibrant as $S$-algebras, the two right vertical morphisms are weak equivalences and the two epimorphisms are fibrations. I do not know how to proceed next.

Any help would be appreciated, or a reference to a similar result. Even an intermediate result would be interesting: for example if $r$ is moreover a fibration, what do we know about $\phi^{!}r$?

Comment: You can expect this to be false, especially when the map ϕ is not injective.  The reason for this is that ϕ^! needs to be derived (e.g., by cofibrantly replacing its arguments), which amounts to taking some kind of a free resolution.

Comment: You could look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06485 and at https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06055 and references there. To summarize, one answer is: if the codomain is a free right module over the domain (and one can relax this a bit more).

Comment: @DmitriP. hm, I do not think I fully understand this tho. Perhaps my knowledge of the derived world is not sufficient enough, but why do you need to take free resolutions? Is this obstruction then resolved if we would start from e.g. r:X -> Y where X is already a cofibrant object?

Comment: @Lilolance: Cofibrancy in this case amounts to being a retract of a certain free object. You would need both X and Y to be cofibrant, or satisfy some similar condition, in order for ϕ^! to be derived.